# Tabs repeat on click page action

Tags: google-chrome-extension

background.html:

```
// Called when the url of a tab changes.
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status === "loading") {
      if (tab.url.indexOf('google.com') > -1) {
      // ... show the page action.
      chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
      chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){

    chrome.tabs.create({url: "facebook.com", "active":true});

      });      
}
}
};


// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

So, I go on google, click page action, in new tab opens facebook. I make **new tab with google again**, click page action and it opens 2 facebook-tabs. Its strange, because I need - 1 click on page action - 1 new tab. How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding an event listener every time your tab changes.

Since you're calling `checkForValidUrl` every time a tab changes, `chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener` is also called every time a tab changes. Now your `pageAction` has two event listeners doing the same thing. You can verify this by changing tabs multiple times and see that it will open as many Facebook tabs as you have changed tabs.

To fix this, of course, you should remove the following from `checkForValidUrl`:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "facebook.com", "active":true});
});
```

and put it outside, for example, after you set up your listener for `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`.

Comment: oh, thanks. I think, that "if page action shown, then if clicked .. etc". Thnaks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing the page action "lives" with the background page and is thus always around and ready to be hidden or shown. (i.e. the listener stays around with it) As a side note, your question made me wonder how to alter an already-set listener. The answer is not documented: `chrome.pageAction.onClicked` has more methods than just `addListener`, including `hasListener` and `removeListener`. Of course, you'd need to keep a reference to your callback around to use them.